# Font Awesome 4.7 to 5 broken?

Tags: font-awesome-5

Be forgiving, I am new to css let alone fontawesome :-)
I wanted to have a nice set of rating stars 0-5 and I managed it *sort of* using 4.7

https://jsfiddle.net/BoxRec/p3zgeLbt/36

```
content: "\f005\f006\f006\f006\f006";
```

However I needed half stars to complete the look and this required going to fontawesome 5

https://jsfiddle.net/BoxRec/p3zgeLbt/38

```
content: "\f005\f089\f006\f006\f006";
```

So I used the 5 library and now I now have the half star \f5c0 but the full star \f005 renders the same as the empty star \f006

https://jsfiddle.net/BoxRec/p3zgeLbt/46/

```
content: "\f005\f5c0\f006\f006\f006";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet#use), you can see that `\f006` is gone in FontAwesome 5. I would **(not a css guy)** just use `before` and `after` tags to make the same effect. Regular vs solid is just changing the font weight.

note that I changed the font-family to `'Font Awesome\ 5 Free'`

```
i.star {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffaa00;
  font-style: normal;
}

i.s1::before {
  content: "\f005";
  font-weight: 900;
}
i.s1::after {
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005";
  font-weight: 200;
}
i.s1-5::before {
  content: "\f005\f5c0";
  font-weight: 900;
}
i.s1-5::after {
  content: "\f005\f005\f005";
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

Had to add this to the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
```

Comment: Many thanks, I implemented your idea ....https://jsfiddle.net/BoxRec/p3zgeLbt/69/ I had to use shims /200a to try and line up, it looks like the half char is a slightly thinner width.